# How to reconstruct an sf object from the coordinate matrix made by st_coordinates?

Tags: coordinates, r-sf

`st_coordinates` provides a matrix of coordinates for all rings in a simple feature column (for each simple feature geometry, outer rings and holes of all polygons). Is there a way to do the reverse, i.e. to build an sfc from a matrix of the same format as the output of `st_coordinates`?

As a reminder, here is the structure of a `st_coordinates` output:

```
        X   Y L1 L2 L3
 [1,]   0   0  1  1  1
 [2,] -10   0  1  1  1
 [3,] -10 -10  1  1  1
 [4,]   0 -10  1  1  1
 [5,]   0   0  1  1  1
 [6,]   1   1  1  1  2
 [7,]  11   1  1  1  2
 [8,]  11  11  1  1  2
 [9,]   1  11  1  1  2
[10,]   1   1  1  1  2
[11,]   2   2  2  1  2
[12,]   3   2  2  1  2
[13,]   3   3  2  1  2
[14,]   2   3  2  1  2
[15,]   2   2  2  1  2
[16,]   5  -2  1  2  2
[17,]  10  -2  1  2  2
[18,]  10  -1  1  2  2
[19,]   5  -1  1  2  2
[20,]   5  -2  1  2  2
```

corresponding to this image:

[image]

How to make the sf object?

Answer (score 2):

Via using a data.frame one could do:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
d <- 
  structure(list(X = c(0L, -10L, -10L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 
                       1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L), 
                 Y = c(0L, 0L, -10L, -10L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                       3L, 2L, -2L, -2L, -1L, -1L, -2L),
                 L1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                 L2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                 L3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))   %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
  group_by(L1, L2, L3) %>% 
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
# to visualise
d %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
# to generate polygons
d %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

**Addendum**

Response to the righteous comment by Jean-Luc Dupouey with respect to hole, I guess this code should address that:

```
d.po <-
  d %>% 
  group_by(L2, L3) %>% 
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% 
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>% 
  ungroup()
# visualise
d.po %>% 
  unite("group", L2:L3) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = group))
```

Comment: Thanks @einar for your proposal. However, it does not produce the right object. The hole (column L1, according to sf specifications) is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. A possible approach is to use `sf::st_polygon()` call.

The call expects argument in format of a list - the first item is outer boundary, and then holes as required.

As an example consider this code, built on top of the well known & much loved NC shapefile.

What it does is that it decomposes the Mecklenburg county to coordinate matrix of boundaries, and then builds it up to a `sfg` >> `sfc` >> `sf` object.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%  
  filter(CNTY_ID == 2041) # Mecklenburg, as in Charlotte of Mecklenburg-Strelitz

#coordinates of Mecklenburg cnty
coords <- st_coordinates(shape)

class(coords)
[1] "matrix" "array" 

head(coords)
             X        Y L1 L2 L3
[1,] -81.04930 35.15153  1  1  1
[2,] -81.02396 35.14903  1  1  1
[3,] -81.00728 35.16325  1  1  1
[4,] -81.00152 35.19599  1  1  1
[5,] -81.01405 35.24990  1  1  1
[6,] -80.97964 35.33327  1  1  1

#a polygon from coords
meck_cnty <- st_polygon(x = list(coords[, 1:2])) %>%  # just X and Y please
  st_sfc() %>%  # from sfg to sfc
  st_sf() # from sfc to sf

class(meck_cnty)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

plot(meck_cnty)
```

[image: mecklenburg county outline]

Comment: Thanks. But your code works for one polygon only. My question was for general sf objects, such as the matrix given in the initial question (including multipolygons, holes...).

Comment: It should be in principle possible to build the list of lists required by `st_multipolygon()` call - either via nested for loops or lapply calls - based on the combinations of L1, L2 and L3 return values of a `st_coordinates` call; the only assumption needed seems only whether you are reconstructing a mutipolygon or a multiline. Unfortunately I don't have a piece of code ready that would do that on hand.